# Как можно узнать статистику приложения и обязательно ли для этого подключать Google Analytics?

Tags: android

Как можно узнать статистику приложения и обязательно ли для этого подключать Google Analytics?

Answer (score 3):

Можете сами заказать сервер, поднять базу данных на нем и из приложения отправлять различные запросы туда, сигнализирующие о выполнении некоторых действий пользователем. 
Затем, надо будет реализовать отображение какой-то выборки из вашей базы.

Или, вы можете подключить Google Analytics (есть и аналоги), и он сделает все вышеперечисленное за вас, и в лучшем виде.

**UPD:**
Также, некая статистика видна в консоли разработчика Google play,  после того, как вы выложили приложение в маркет (с задержкой в 24 часа). Там видна:

- Статистика установок (уникальных, нет, по странам, по версиям системы, приложения, тд)
- Статистика удалений и тд

Статистика непосредственно использования приложения в developer console без интеграции с Analytics не видна.

Comment: а в консоли разработчика Google Play можно посмотреть статистику?

Comment: @Вячеслав смотрите обновление

Comment: а как часто статистика  в консоли разработчика обновляется?

Comment: Обновляется раз в сутки @Вячеслав

Comment: А можете в двух словах рассказать о Идентификаторе отслеживания. Я так понял, чтобы подключить Analytics нужно добавить некоторые параметры в AndroidManifest в приложении. Ну а если приложение уже опубликовано, тогда как подключить Analytics?

Comment: Задавайте отдельный вопрос. А мой можете сделать правильным) А вообще, придется обновление выпускать. @Вячеслав